# Gnucash: no transactions to match?

Tags: gnucash

I recently started doing a quite good job in proactively entering the expense transactions in Gnucash and I organised everything so that the balances match bank balances for the last couple of years. Now I tried to import last week's transactions - most of which I had already entered by hand and I encountered this message: **"OFX file imported, 2 transactions processed, no transactions to match"**. What does this message mean? I have looked at the ofx as a text file and I can see the transactions there, they already exist in the gnucash database.

Comment: To oversimplify the goals of the GnuCash transaction import process, they might be to (1) import transactions from a file that do not already exist in the GnuCash database, and (2) DO NOT import transactions that already exist in GnuCash.  The "message" is slightly confusing, but it sounds as though the import process did not import transactions that already exist in GnuCash - which means the system is working properly.  If I have misunderstood the situation, please edit your query to provide more details.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I think this is exactly the case. Next day I found that I by mistake I had been trying to import previous fortnight's data that were already in GnuCash. Once I got to the right data it was alright. The message is a bit cryptic though and it got me experimenting with re-import of the same file - which confused me a bit further. When I get the chance I will try to understand better the difference between U+R and R checkbox columns and update my question with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that means those transactions were already imported. You have probably already imported that file.